# Find min and max of a list of number given in str format

Tags: python, string

I am trying to build a function that takes in a list of numbers as a single string and returns the highest and lowest value as a string as well.

Like:
`high_and_low("8 3 -5 42 -1 0 0 -9 4 7 4 -4")` -> `"42 -9"`

So far, this is what I tried but it does not work as expected.

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
    # ... n=numbers.replace(' ',',')
    numbers=float(n) 
    l=min(numbers)
    h=max(numbers)
    return "{} {}".format(h,l)

high_and_low("8 3 -5 42 -1 0 0 -9 4 7 4 -4")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: "We cannot convert into int.": well, convert to float.

Comment: Split the string. Write your own "less than" comparator for strings with numbers in. Find the minimum and maximum in exactly the same way that you would using "less than" (<) for ints.

Comment: @9769953 I think he tried to convert the entire string to an integer, instead of splitting the string and then converting each string in the array.

Comment: shows value error for converting to float.

Comment: This is the code i used

Comment: def high_and_low(numbers):
    # ...
    n=numbers.replace(' ',',')
    numbers=float(n)
    l=min(numbers)
    h=max(numbers)
    return "{} {}".format(h,l)
high_and_low("8 3 -5 42 -1 0 0 -9 4 7 4 -4")

Comment: Please [edit] your question and the code in your question, not in a comment. Please also format the code with a code block for readability.

Comment: I edited the question and inserted the code. This would now lead to the next required clarification: what's the problem with this code? Does it fail? Now that you have the answer, it doesn't matter anymore. But to make your questions easier to answer, consider specifying all required details and don't rely on people to guess. See also [mcve].

Comment: In case of only one number,it raised an error "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected at least 2, got 1)".

Comment: I think you can solve it by yourself — make a combination of your original code and the answer you got. In case you can't solve this, please ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string of whitespace separated numbers, one way to find the min and max would be:

```
num_string = "8 3 -5 42 -1 0 0 9 4 7 4 -4 42 -9"
num_min, *_, num_max = sorted(map(int, num_string.split()))
```

This will split the string on the spaces, into a list of the numbers, which will then be mapped to integers, before being sorted ascendingly. The first & last items are then assigned to `num_min` & `num_max` with the rest being thrown away.

Comment: '*_'  means?....

Comment: It throws the rest of the items away. Actually assigns them to `_`, but the convention is that `_` is a throwaway variable.

Comment: whats the other way of this problem??